# Where to put Handlebars.registerHelper function in node.js project?

Tags: node.js, express-handlebars, registerhelper

I want to increase "totalPrice" by 10 and then display it in handlebars templates . Here z some snippet of my handlebar file.
checkout.hbs

```
<ul class="shipping__method">
       <li>Shipping <span>$ 10</span></li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="total__amount">
   <li>Order Total <span>Rs. {{increasePrice totalPrice}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

For that i write this in my app.js file

```
  var expressHbs =  require('express-handlebars');
    app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}))
     app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
    expressHbs.registerHelper ('increasePrice', function (price) {
      price+=10;
      return price;
     })
```

And then i got error  expressHbs.registerHelper is not a function. Then i came to know to write it like this

```
 var hbs = expressHbs.create({
 helpers: {
   increasePrice: function(price) {
     price+=20;
     return price;
   }
  }
})
```

And then i got error like "missing Helper: "increasePrice" ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‍ **You see** this code below , an example code using `express` and `express-handlebars`:

**index.js**

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var expressHbs =  require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

var hbs = expressHbs.create({});

// register new function
hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('increasePrice', function(price) {
  price+=10;
  return price;
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home', {
    layout: false,
    totalPrice: 300,
  });
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
});
```

Now create file `home.hbs` in views, and put this code below  in there.

**home.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Example APP</title>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="shipping__method">
    <li>Shipping: Total Price <span>$ {{ totalPrice }}</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="total__amount">
    <li>Order Total <span>Rs. {{increasePrice totalPrice}}</span></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**From the code above** , I hope you can understand now, where you have to put your function.

**For an example:** You can see on my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-fog-1n61o)

I hope it's can help you .

Comment: Ooh! that helps . Thank u